# Identify encoding type

Tags: python, encoding, decoding

I'm in the process of analysing some web log files. There are parameters passed for some requests which are encoded. I tried [this](http://code.google.com/p/hash-identifier/) to decode it, but it cannot identify the encoding schema. Do you have any idea on what this encoding type is?

```
Z6spFdlqDaXMjdoDTiMvPS%2F3g8IAmmW%2FGqTHCw%3D%3D
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That looks like a urlencoded base64 string.

The data seems to be something unreadable so I dumped it in HEX:

```
67AB2915D96A0DA5CC8DDA034E232F3D2FF783C2009A65BF1AA4C70B
```

Some more hints that % sign is followed by two hexadecimal letters e.g. %2F is / that output ends with == with is very typically for base 64

Comment: Thanks rekire..It seems so :)

Comment: You are welcome, I also tried to analyze the data but I failed... If this is helpful enough for you feel free to accept my answer :-)